# Asp.Net MVC Reaching The Property Using Many To Many Relation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, asp.net-mvc-5

In my model, a person(HrPerson) can have one more than titles(HrPersonTitle). So i have created below model to establish many to many relation between two models.

**HrPerson Model :**

```
public class HrPerson
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<HrPersonTitle> HrPersonTitle { get; set; }
    }
```

**HrPersonTitle Model :**

```
public class HrPersonTitle
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public  ICollection <HrPerson> HrPerson { get; set; }
    }
```

**In my DbContext Class :**

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<HrPerson>()
            .HasMany(s => s.HrPersonTitle)
            .WithMany(c => c.HrPerson)
            .Map(t =>
                 {
                     t.MapLeftKey("HrPersonId")
                     .MapRightKey("HrPersonTitleId")
                     .ToTable("HrMapPersonTitle");
                 });
    }
```

When i updated the DB, **HrMapPersonTitle** has been created. I think it is OK for many to many relation(?)

My question is in controller action. My aim is to get all *title's name* which belongs to any person. I implemented the below code.

**Controller :**

```
public PartialViewResult _ViewHrPersonTitle(int? personId)
{
    var Titles = db.HrPersonTitle.Where(p => p.HrPerson.**(ID)???** = personId)

    return PartialView(Titles);
}
```

It seems i could not reach the HrPerson-ID property from HrPersonTitle model. I think it is what it should be. 
I wonder what is the best way to get the all Titles which belongs to a Person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you can just do:

```
public PartialViewResult _ViewHrPersonTitle(int? personId)
{
    var person = db.HrPerson.Find(personId);
    var titles = person.HrPersonTitle.ToList(); // .ToList() is optional

    return PartialView(titles);
}
```

Also, the reason why you can't reach HrPerson directly from the Title entity is beacuse you didn't declare it `virtual` in your entity class.
The entity framework needs navigation properties to be virtual for lazy loading them / use with dynamic proxies.

If you don't declare them `virtual`, they will **not** be lazily loaded by default. They can still be loaded eagerly by

`.Include(..)`

or lazily by

`.Load()` (Explicitly Loading).

But for your use-case, probably it's best to just go the automatic way.

Comment: Thank you very much.. So for the performance, which one is better ? Leager or lazy loading?

Comment: One more thing, i am not able to use HrMapPersonTitle. For example i want to create a new row in controller but i could not reach it.

Comment: Lazy loading only loads properties when there actually accessed. But if you know exactly what you need, explicitly loading only that might prove better. As for the mapping table not being accessible: An entry there will be created when you create the relationship. As in
``db.HrPerson.Find(personId).add(new HrPersonTitle());``
This will automatically create the entry and it also works the other way around (add to existing HrPersonTitle)