# Asp.Net MVC Reaching The Property Using Many To Many Relation With Mapping Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

You can see my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457084/asp-net-mvc-reaching-the-property-using-many-to-many-relation) which related with many to many relation but with auto generated mapping table.

I have 2 model, HrTraining and HrPerson. Any people can be assigned to one or more Trainings. You can see my model as below

```
public class HrTraining
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HrMapTrainingPerson> HrMapTrainingPerson { get; set; }
}

public class HrMapTrainingPerson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int HrTrainingId { get; set; }
    public int HrPersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual HrTraining HrTraining { get; set; }
    public virtual HrPerson HrPerson { get; set; }
}

public class HrPerson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HrMapTrainingPerson> HrMapTrainingPerson { get; set; }
}
```

How can i take all training objects which assingned to a person with efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find a person, and get all the trainings assigned to it? There are lot of ways.. but using your models, this could be something like this

```
var trPersons = dbContext.HrPerson.Find(idPerson).HrMapTrainingPerson.ToList();

foreach(var trPerson in trPersons) {

    var training = trPerson.HrTraining;

    //do what you want, here you can get trPerson.HrTraining.Name for instance

}
```